# Unable to load the image in the Pygame GUI

Tags: python, pygame, raspbian

Hey Guys I'm using Raspberry Pi OS in my desktop I'm on a mission to make a game using Pygame in Python but I can't load the image in the Pygame GUI it's getting some errors.
I have tried copying it's path and paste but the same error is visible hope you guys can solve this

```
import pygame 
pygame.init()
disp = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))
pygame.display.set_caption("Hello")
pygame.image.load("img.png")
pygame.display.update()
```

OUTPUT : pygame 1.9.4.post1
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
ALSA lib bluealsa-pcm.c:763:(_snd_pcm_bluealsa_open) Couldn't get BlueALSA PCM: PCM not found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code has no errors, just open, and close because you don't have a while loop to keep it open.
The alsa error should be asociated to your audio drivers... Check if you have any.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is a good advice, but try to use older version of Python. I noticed that several errors occur when I use Pygame with the recent version of Python.